# Opencart Styling Product description

Tags: opencart

I have inserted data in table format in text editor of opencart. But this description is visible in the form of paragraph on front end of the store. How can I display product description in table form.  In C:\Xamp\htdocs\opencart-2.0.3.1\upload\catalog\view\theme\default\template\product\category.tpl line 102

I am unable to convert this paragraph description into table format. so that the data entered in table format from admin should be displayed in table format not paragraph

Comment: can you explain it a little bit better,i didnt really undetstand anything,or give an example

Comment: for example I have a product and its details and I want those details to be displayed in table under its nam. The styling that I do using description editor will be displayed after I click that product but I want that table to be visible on category page.

Answer (score 0):

if you get the html code of table in front then you need to use

```
html_entity_decode($description);
```

which convert you html tags into its respective.